# How do I determine the page in which manually added ToC entries are typeset?

Tags: cross-referencing

The title says it all. Assume I use two `\addtocontents` in a document and I want to know whether or not their argument will be typeset in the same page of the ToC.

The simple idea of placing a `\label` and then using `\pageref`, as in

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\pageref{a}\pageref{b}

\tableofcontents

\addtocontents{toc}{a\label{a}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\newpage b\label{b}}

\end{document}
```

fails and produces the expected warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.
```

Comment: It works (on the third LaTeX run) if you `\protect` the `\label` commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

..... fragile command in a moving argument...

```
\addtocontents{toc}{a\protect\label{a}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\newpage b\protect\label{b}}
```